# Blender Rigify Jaw Rig Conflicting mouth chain layer

Tags: python, rigging, rigify

[image]
So I was wondering why I get this error RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'jaw_master.001': Conflicting mouth chain layer on ORG-lip.T.L.006: 0 and 1
Incorrect armature for type 'skin_jaw'

And I found the problem, Jaw rig loops must not be crossing each other like i have in the following picture [image]
Correct me if i am wrong.